# Google App Engine - use key_name or ReferenceProperty for quick lookup

Tags: google-app-engine, nosql

I have a user account model and a profile model for each user. Currently I am setting the key_name of both to a unique generated ID. The ID is stored in the session object and that way I can lookup either the user account or profile model using the same ID as key_name. Is this the best option or should I use a ReferenceProperty instead to connect the account and the profile?

```
class UserAccount(db.Model):
    dateCreated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    userid = db.StringProperty()
    password = db.StringProperty()
    emailLower = db.StringProperty()

class Profile(db.Model):
    dateCreated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    firstName = db.StringProperty()
    firstNameUpper = db.StringProperty()
    lastName = db.StringProperty()
    lastNameUpper = db.StringProperty()
    topicTags = db.StringListProperty()
    about = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    experience = db.StringListProperty()


account = UserAccount(key_name=uniqueid)
profile = Profile(key_name=uniqueid)
```

Later i can look up either by some id. I imagine this limits me to only one profile per user account which should be fine. Is there any benefit for me using a ReferenceProperty in one or both of the UserAccount and Profile objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you can compute the uniqueid, your mechanism should be just fine.  There isn't much benefit to using a ReferenceProperty.